# CoreNLP SemanticGraph - search for edges with specific lemmas

Tags: text-mining

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP's dependency parser, and wondering how to make a generic search for SemanticEdge(s) with specific head lemma, dependent lemma, and lexical relationship. For example, if I have an actual dependency like this:

- dobj(discover-4, insights-6)

How do I search for it using lemmas instead of the literal word and the index? Basically I want to be able to pattern match the parts of the dependency graph using generic rules...

Comment: After reviewing the API, it doesn't look like there is a direct method to do it (please correct me if I'm wrong, that's why I posted this question here!). I'm thinking of using some sort of collection where the dependency edges would be stored as indexed entries (maybe the relationship or head word would be indexed), and then use generic Java search patterns to find the desired edges?